# Sub Exponential compleixty

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I saw in the below link that 2<sup>n<sup>O(1)</sup></sup>
is sub exponential complexity. I do not understand the difference between 2<sup>n</sup> and 2<sup>n<sup>O(1)</sup></sup>. Aren't they the same as O(1) evaluates to 1?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems

I have algorithms of subset sum problem that have been solved in 2<sup>n</sup> -1 runtime steps thus having O(2<sup>n</sup>) complexity. Is that sub polynomial time? If it is then it violates the exponential time hypothesis(ETH) and proves P not equal to NP!

I also know that brute force for such problems runs in O(2<sup>n</sup>). So what is the difference in this complexity and sub exponential one?

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Did I see something about a link?

Comment: The link uses little-o, not big-O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(1) is definitely not the same as 1.

If *f(x)* is in O(1), then so is *g(x)*=*c*×*f(x)*. For example, *f(x)*=(*x*−1)⁄*x* is clearly in O(1) since its asymptotic to 1, and so is *g(x)*=(*x*−1) ⁄ 2 *x*, whose asymptote is 0.5.

But 2<sup>*n*<sup>1</sup></sup> (=2<sup>*n*</sup>) is quite different from 2<sup>*n*<sup>1⁄2</sup></sup> (=2<sup>√*n*</sup>). The latter certainly could be described as subexponential.